# Не передается $_GET

Tags: php

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {$id = $_GET['id'];}
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE id='$id'",$db);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

﻿
Выходит, что переменная `id` неопределена.

> Notice: Undefined index: id

Может, потому что `register_globals Off`?

Есть страница со списком:

```
 <?php 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id,name FROM students",$db);
    $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    do {
    printf ("<p><a href='students_view.php?=%s'>%s</a><br></p>",$myrow["id"],$myrow["name"]);
    }
    while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
    ?>
```

Вот сгенерир. код:

```
<a href="students_view.php?=1">Руслан</a>
```

Comment: добавил сген. html код той строки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) id может быть не определён, если `$_GET['id']` - не передано.
2) `register_globals` - директива, которая переносит содержимое `$_GET` и `$_POST` в глобальную область видимости, и в данном случае это не имеет значения.

Вы не верно вызываете скрипт, надо так: students_view.php?id=2
Либо ( если `id` как-то передается ) изменить `$_GET`  на `$_POST` или `$_REQUEST`

Вообще стоит переписать как-то так:

```
if ( !isset($_GET['id']) || ( ( $id = (int)$_GET['id'] ) < 1 ) ) die("Error of ID");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE id='$id'",$db);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Вот и ошибка:

```
<p><a href='students_view.php?=1'>Алик</a><br></p>
```

А надо:

```
<p><a href='students_view.php?id=1'>Алик</a><br></p>
```

Т.е. измените php:

```
printf ("<p><a href='students_view.php?id=%s'>%s</a><br></p>",$myrow["id"],$myrow["name"]);
```

Comment: 1) Ну вот он не хочет передавать id значение $_GET['id']
2) спасибо за инфу
3) указана таблица

Comment: добавил в вопрос код

Comment: ДОбавил html код страницы со списком

Comment: Спасибо огромное ВАМ!!!

Answer (score 1):

`$id = (int) $_GET['id'];` - если `$_GET['id'];` не задана, id будет равна 0. Потом можно просто проверить `if($id){...}`.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM name_table WHERE id='$id'",$db);
```

Это во первых, во-вторых ты, наверно, не правильно тоже передал.
В конце этого кода поставь

> var_dump($_GET);

И напиши что вывело

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: id in students_view.php on line 4
array(0) { }
Вот что теперь выходит

Comment: Это значит ты вообще не одной переменной GET методом не передаёшь

Answer (score 0):

```
result = mysql_query("SELECT * WHERE id='$idus'",$db);
```

Вот тут вы ошиблись или правильно написали? $idus или просто $id?

Comment: Правильно $id, и все равно не получается